# Excel crashes after SaveAs

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have inherited an excel project, which I’ve been tasked to automate and develop further.

Use case being

- An order comes in
- User opens the base (root) excel file
- Types in the relevant info (customer, order, data, tasks, etc)
- And saves the new task file in a folder with tasks in progress
- Leaving the base (root) excel basic and ready for next order.

The new task file needs to have a certain file name structure, which has been sorted.

My problem comes in on `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename`.

As I step through <kbd>F5</kbd> the lines, it goes through all the steps, creates the filename, shows the Save As UI, correctly shows the right folder and suggested filename, and actually saves the file. As I come out of ErrHandler and the last `Application.EnableEvents = yes` - it crashes. It seems to either be closing the base file, opening the new, or transfer active workbook to the new save file.

Which is fine, if it could stop crashing.

```
If criticalInput then
    Msgbox “U been bad, U Shall not PASS!”, vbCritical ‘Not actual text or box showing, just for demo.
Else
    Dim fileSaveName As Variant

    '### It Crashes after saving (possible at opening)
    fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
    InitialFileName:=tasksfolder & "\" & suggestFilename, _
    fileFilter:="Excel-projectmappe med aktive makroer (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")

    If fileSaveName <> False Then
        '### here is where you would save your file
        DoEvents ‘ Debugging research tells this should be here. Not that is changes anything.
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileSaveName ‘ During dev this has been disabled.
    End If ' SaveAs
End If ' criticalInput

ErrHandler:
    '## Reset back to default
    Application.DefaultFilePath = strDefault

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Debugging

- I can save the file just nicely, if I disable SaveAs and work only on the base (root) excel file.
- I can open the new task file and save it nicely. (Just being a bugger about overwriting, Y/N)
- Debugging research said I needed a DoEvents prior to SaveAs
- Debugging research also said only to have the most relevant references present (in my case unselect OLE Automation)
- During debugging, I’ve also created, AfterSave() and Open(). They triggers normally during normal operation, but fails when SaveAs has crashed. Eg as I disable SaveAs or when I open the excel book normally.

```
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler    
    If Success Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        'MsgBox "Success save", vbInformation ' for debugging purposes.
    End If    
    ErrHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    'MsgBox "I haz been opened, yehawww", vbInformation ' debugging
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `ActiveWorkbook` to `ThisWorkbook`?

Comment: Noted, that didn't come up in my research.

Comment: If you have an error handler, it would be useful to know if the code execution just fell into it, or it got there because there was an error.  Typically you'd Exit Sub before the error handler, and reserve the code in that block for when there's actually a problem.

Comment: For all the ErrHandlers I found, it is the last thing that happens, used both to catch and handle error and also reset such things as EnableEvents.

Comment: Since it's crashing after `EnableEvents = yes`, that implies that there is an event with a coding problem.  In my experience crashes are almost always caused by mishandled objects.  It's a pain to troubleshoot someone else's work but I'd suggest you start by making sure `Option Explicit` is the first line in every module, and then compile. This will raise an error with undeclared or mis-referenced variables/object/properties/etc. Also, why automatically re-enable events after a save error instead of finding the cause?

Comment: If your code has errors then typically you want to know about it.  So I'd suggest exiting before the error handler and doing clean-up such as re-enabling events) in the "regular" code.  Then put a Msgbox in your error handler so you know something isn't working as expected.   Why are error handlers disabled to begin with?  That would be a good place to begin.

Comment: @ashleedawg Option Explicit is in there. I have gone through the attributes.

Comment: @Tim Williams It goes through the entire code, it does save, after the final line in the errHandler it crashes. There are no errors before that point. It just moves naturally into the ErrHandlers and resets the code.  The code does what is required, it just crashes after it completes 100% success rate.

Comment: Is anything being written to the Windows event logs? If I understand what you mean by "crashes" correctly, you should be getting App crash events.

Comment: `If fileSaveName  False Then` won't compile. Try `If fileSaveName  = False Then`

Comment: As I got into the project again, I went over the suggestions. Active vs Thisworkbook, no difference. Option explicit on everything, a few things changed. Found some entries in the Eventlog, an error 1000 and few apps tested (one could look like like those 'MS' 'Windows' Support call thingies). I worked once (maybe), then it went back to crashing. It said Excel and MSO.dll were crashing. An app I trust and use regularly didn't find anything wrong. Also I tested it on another PC, same result.

Some good news, and back at crashing.

Also thank you for bonking me over the head, I needed it.

Comment: @DoStuffZ I have identical problem crashing at `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=file_name,             FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False, ReadOnlyRecommended:=False`. Bizzarely, this macro works (no crashes) in Excel 365/Win 10 and initially worked when I started using it on Excel 2010/Win 7. But now it crashes everytime on Excel 2010/Win 7

Comment: @rockhammer My contract with the company has ended. In the end the solution was abandoned, and is now done manually. I would expect the solution to work/crash by each iteration/version of Office 365/2010, pending updates and Q&A. Last I heard they bugged the $A$1 locks, might be fixed again.